# Is there a USA map of fuel grades (elevation-specific REGular / 85 / 87)?

Tags: usa, automobiles, maps, stopovers

It would appear that in the US of A, most fuel is generally sold as Regular, Plus (or Midgrade), and Premium, with the actual specification being hidden in small print.

My car requires 87, which goes as Regular at sea-level in Houston or San Jose, but the Regular in Denver is 85.   Without getting into too much details, it would appear that although modern cars would still run OK with 85 in Denver, the experts do suggest that such use is no longer optimal.  Not to mention the possibility of filling up at an elevation only to continue the trip towards the sea level.

As such, when doing cross-country travel, tools like GasBuddy.com may be misleading in advertising you suboptimal fuel.  E.g., a combination of fuel tax jurisdiction and fuel grade may amount for significant differences between nearby stations.

Is there a solution?  Automated would be best, but a map of mappings between "REG" et al and "85"/ "87" et al would be great as well.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, [federal law requires](https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/complying-ftc-fuel-rating-rule) stations display the actual octane rating on a sticker at the pump, as in an actual number rather than a word. That's not helpful to you if you're trying to find a station in advance to compare prices, but you should always know what you're getting before you buy.

Comment: @ZachLipton, yes, exactly -- the numbers are always displayed once you're at the pump, but GasBuddy isn't regulated. :-)

Comment: There's a partial list at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._State_Fuel_Octane_Standards

Comment: @NateEldredge, that's basically an empty table!  I think I recall seeing some such table, but it was likewise half-empty, plus the values didn't seem to be correct to start with.  Realistically, the map would be unlikely to be divided with state lines, as many states, from Texas to Colorado, have quite varying levels of elevation.

Comment: My experience is that most states start at 87 and those that offer 85, usually also have higher octane options.  Is mapping out your gas stations in advamce that important?

Comment: Does it really vary by elevation within states?  Colorado has elevations from 3300 to 14000 feet but I believe 85 octane is sold throughout the state.  Conversely, California varies from -282 to over 14000 but I have never seen anything lower than 87 there.

Comment: @NateEldredge, in West Texas around Lubbock, was offered 86, 88 and 91 at United Express.  No 87.  Are you sure California still has 87 even in Truckee?

Comment: @Tom, your statement is not true; I haven't seen a single station in Lubbock to have 87, for example.

Comment: @cnst - I said "usually" not "always".

Comment: @cnst: Interesting about Texas.  I seem to recall 86 and 88 are common (maybe universal?) in New Mexico.  As to California, I don't recall specifically but I have certainly driven around Truckee in the past and I think I would have noticed different fuel octane.

Answer (score 1):

No such map currently exists as of 2017. Your best bet is therefore to find a cheap gas station through GasBuddy and then hope their higher-octane fuels are also reasonably priced.